# Will installing Windows 10 ISO on Windows 7 (genuine) make Windows 10 genuine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, iso-image, windows-10-upgrade

I'm having trouble with Windows servers or my Windows update. Every time download gets stuck at magic 84%. Now I am thinking of installing Windows 10 through an ISO on a Windows 7 laptop. Will ***installing Windows 10 with an ISO over Windows 7*** (genuine) make Windows 10 genuine?
Can anyone explain me the **exact steps to get that iso from installing the iso keeping the windows genuine.**

Comment: Yes, you can use the ISO from the Media Creation Tool released by Microsoft. You will have to do an upgrade using the ISO before you can clean install. It will be genuine/activated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to upgrade, though. There’s no need to create a thumb drive or anything. Here’s what I did:

- Mount ISO using Windows’ 8.1 integrated ISO mounter
- Start Setup
- Wait for readiness check
- Start upgrade

It then copies all files to your disk and reboots to setup. Upgrading will take quite some time.

Comment: It looks like OP is using Windows 7.

Comment: Then just use DaemonTools or whatever…

Comment: @MC10 That just means he just cannot use the Windows-integrated mounter. He can still use Virtual CloneDrive or whatever.

Comment: Does mounting an iso and upgrading to windows 10 from windows 7 for 1st time will keep my windows 10 genuine.  And tell me more about mounting iso, the exact steps.

Comment: I already confirmed that. There’s nothing complicated involved. You can also use 7-Zip to unpack the ISO if you’re more comfortable with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the upgrade from a Windows 10 ISO and make your copy genuine as long as you meet the following criteria:

1. You have a genuine copy of Windows 7.
2. You have Service Pack 1 installed on your copy of Windows 7.
3. You do the upgrade within the first year of launch of Windows 10.
4. And lastly you perform the setup of Windows 10 from Windows 7 (doing an in place upgrade).

Also, just make sure that the ISO that you have is not the preview version of W10. Meaning it should be build 10240 which is the RTM version.

Comment: There are couple inaccuracies that are worth pointing out.  Pointing out build 10240 is a mistake because in a very short amount of time the current build will NOT be 10240.  Second, you can perform the upgrade at any point, the initial upgrade just won't be free after July 29th 2016.  Thirdly, your 4th step, isn't even a complete sentence.  Lastly older preview installations can be used, it is a horrible idea, but they can be used until they expire at least.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree that in a short period of time 10240 will no longer be the current build. But for point 2 and 3 (and even point 4), I answered specifically to what the the OP was asking (_can the upgrade be done and still be genuine?_). And yes, I have modified point number 4 to make it a complete sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If your current version of Windows 7/8/8.1 is genuine, then the installation of windows 10 will be genuine.